# In-App Subscription content

Tags: iphone, ios4, in-app-purchase, subscription

I am trying to implement an In-App Subscription for Iphone. The concept is this:

- In my app, I have an sqlite with some hierarchical data.
- These hierarchical data need to be updated every 2-3 months, so I am offering a yearly subscription via IAP.
- Once a new update is enabled, the in-app will be PUSH Notified? so that users know they need to download it.

So far I understand this from the documents. So I went to the itunesconnect site and setup a dummy app to test my code.

- Where do I put the digital content for the updates? (a PLIST or XML datafile with the entries). I can't find any "upload content" button, except for the screenshot one of the update.
- How will the user know that his subscription is over? I have to implement this or is it something that Itunes Platform notifies?
- Can I update the database located on mainBundle once the files are downloaded?

Thanks for any reply, 
I am in a fuss here because subscription is a grey area for me, and I can't find any examples.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the content on your own server, or you could use a service provider like http://urbanairship.com/. They offer a subscription service for $0.15 per user and month.

the mainBundle is not writeable. you have to save the file to another location. Like the library or documents directory.

Regarding question 2, you have to implement the whole in-app-purchase management on your own, so I think you have to take care of subscription periods too. But I'm not sure about this.

Comment: Is there any example using custom-made server? Or a ready package for a content server which by tweaking the code can be used for Ios apps?